# getting elements name list from a xml using scala or javascript

Tags: javascript, scala

My xml file looks like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
<city>
<ID>1</ID>
<Name>Kabul</Name>
<CountryCode>AFG</CountryCode>
<District>Kabol</District>
<Population>1780000</Population>
</city>
<city>
<ID>2</ID>
<Name>Qandahar</Name>
<CountryCode>AFG</CountryCode>
<District>Qandahar</District>
<Population>237500</Population>
</city>
<city>
<ID>3</ID>
<Name>Herat</Name>
<CountryCode>AFG</CountryCode>
<District>Herat</District>
<Population>186800</Population>
</city>
</root>
```

I need to get the element names ("ID","Name","CountryCode","District","Population") using scala or javascript. please help.

Comment: So what does JavaScript have to do with this? Did you search Parse XML Scala?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For JavaScript, just to it as you would do it with elements in the DOM.
(But don't forget to parse the XML!)

```js
var xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><root><city><ID>1</ID><Name>Kabul</Name><CountryCode>AFG</CountryCode><District>Kabol</District><Population>1780000</Population></city><city><ID>2</ID><Name>Qandahar</Name><CountryCode>AFG</CountryCode><District>Qandahar</District><Population>237500</Population></city><city><ID>3</ID><Name>Herat</Name><CountryCode>AFG</CountryCode><District>Herat</District><Population>186800</Population></city></root>';

var parser = new DOMParser();
// Parse the xml
var parsedXML = parser.parseFromString(xml, 'text/xml');

// Now get the elements
var id = parsedXML.getElementsByTagName('ID');
var Name = parsedXML.getElementsByTagName('Name');
var countryCode = parsedXML.getElementsByTagName('CountryCode');
var district = parsedXML.getElementsByTagName('District');
var population = parsedXML.getElementsByTagName('Population');

// Get the tag names; because getElementsByTagName returns an array like HTMLCollection, we need to loop through the results like we would with an array
for (var i = 0; i < id.length; i++) {
  console.log(id[i].tagName + " " + Name[i].tagName+ " " + countryCode[i].tagName + " "+ district[i].tagName + " "+ population[i].tagName);
}
```

Comment: Hi CodeF0x, I need the metadata details alone, not the values. that is just.. ("ID","Name","CountryCode","District","Population")

Comment: @stack0114106 So you mean the tag names?

Comment: @stack0114106 Edited. Should fit your requirements now.